# Get elements of arbitrary nested lists

Tags: list, nested, prolog, swi-prolog

I am looking for some predicate in SWI-Prolog to get the elements of some arbitrary nested list. Means, if I e.g. have the list:

```
L = [[a,b], c, [d, [e, f]]]
```

I get as result:

```
R = [a,b,c,d,e,f]
```

Comment: Use flatten/2 - https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=flatten/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @brebs mentioned in his comment, Use predefined predicate [flatten/2](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=flatten/2)

```pl
% ?- flatten([[a,b], c, [d, [e, f]]], R).
%     R = [a, b, c, d, e, f]
```

This user-defined implementation is similar to the predefined one <sup>[1]</sup>

```pl
my_flatten([],[]).
my_flatten([H|T], [H|Res]) :- \+ is_list(H), my_flatten(T, Res), !.
my_flatten([H|T], Res) :- my_flatten(H, Res). % H is list.
```

---

<sup>[1]</sup> except for cases of non-termination like `my_flatten(X,non_list)`. and like `my_flatten([X],[1,2,3,4])`. thanks to @false comment

Comment: *similar to the predefined one* except for cases of non-termination like `my_flatten(X,non_list).` and lack of steadfastness like `my_flatten([X],[1,2,3,4]).`

Comment: @false, right, this is why I described it as "similar".. I've added your comment to the answer as supplement, thanks

Comment: There are many other cases of a different kind, like `my_flatten([[a|b]],Xs).`

Answer (score 3):

The SWI built-in predicate `flatten/2` depends on the very instantiations of the first argument. It thus leads to quite non-relational behavior:

```
?-         flatten(X,[]).
   false.
?- X = [], flatten(X,[]).
   X = [].
?- X = [[],[]], flatten(X,[]).
   X = [[], []].
?- X = [[]|[]], flatten(X,[]).
   X = [[]].
```

Note that there are infinitely many `X` to make `flatten(X,[])` succeed. If you want this to be a relation, there are two choices either enumerate all such solutions, or produce an instantiation error, or just do not terminate (better than an incorrect answer), or delay goals appropriately, or produce some constraints, or produce a resource error. Oh, these have been now 6 choices... ...and lest I forget, you might also combine these options, like first producing some answer substitutions, then delayed goals, then constraints, and then loop quite some time to finally produce a resource error.

In most of such situations, the easiest way to go is to produce instantiation errors like so:

```
flattened(T) -->
   {functor(T,_,_)},  % ensures instantiation
   (  {T = [E|Es]} -> flattened(E), flattened(Es)
   ;  {T = []} -> []
   ;  [T]
   ).
?- phrase(flattened([[]|[]]),Xs).
   Xs = [].
?- phrase(flattened([[]|_]),Xs).
   error(instantiation_error,functor/3).
```